# How do I control widgets added later with gtk in c?

Tags: c, gtk, signals

```
func1();
func2();
...
```

In `func1` there is a `button` widget,and in `func2` a `textview` widget.(Both calls `gtk_box_pack_start` to add widgets to the window, so the order can't be changed.)

I want to operate `textview` when I click on `button` widget.

But at the time I define the callback,`textview` is not available yet.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

First create your widgets, then pack them together, then connect your signals.

Answer (score 0):

So why adding a function func3() in which you connect the signals ?